Why is $z^2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ so much like magnetic field?
Denote $z=x+iy$. I get
$$
z^2\frac{\partial}{\partial z} 
= 
(x^2 -y^2) \frac{\partial }{\partial x} +2xy \frac{\partial }{\partial y}
$$
Then, I use Mathematica to draw it. And find it like a magnetic field. I want to  know if the magnetic field and $z^2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ are just alike or exactly the same, where I assume that the magnet is a point.




The field $\mathbf B={x^2-y^2\choose 2xy}$ may naively look like a magnetic field but it is not because $\nabla\cdot\mathbf B=4x$ which contradicts one of the Maxwell equations.

@KurtG.  Good evening ;-)

The object "$z^2\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$" is a differential operator.  How are you equating an operator to the magnetic flux density??  They are quite distinct objects.

@MarkViola I don't know if it's a good notation, but $\frac \partial {\partial z}$ seems to be $1 \in \mathbb C$ with base at $z.$ Similarly, $\frac \partial {\partial x} = (1, 0)$ and $\frac \partial {\partial y} = (0, 1)$ are vectors with base at $z = (x, y).$

It's because the field is proportional by a position-dependent function to
$$\mathbf{B} = \frac{(x^2-y^2)\mathbf{\hat{i}}+2xy\mathbf{\hat{j}}}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
which is an honest harmonic vector field away from the origin (and represents in magnetostatics a translation invariant dipole distribution supported on the line through the origin that's orthogonal to the plane). The type of plot in the question throws away magnitude information, so the field in the question "looks like" a magnetic field even though it isn't.
